# How to monitor consecutive certain lines in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to monitor my game server log file in order to prevent a packet modification exploit, this requires me to detect such lines

```
[15:02:14] Packet was modified, sent by id: 20, ip: 197.53.29.136:10479
[15:02:14] Packet was modified, sent by id: 20, ip: 197.53.29.136:10479
[15:02:15] Packet was modified, sent by id: 20, ip: 197.53.29.136:10479
[15:02:15] Packet was modified, sent by id: 20, ip: 197.53.29.136:10479
[15:02:15] Packet was modified, sent by id: 20, ip: 197.53.29.136:10479
[15:02:15] Packet was modified, sent by id: 20, ip: 197.53.29.136:10479
```

Once 5 identical lines (containing 'Packet was modified, sent by id:' , the same id and ip - let's ignore the time) are logged within a second (1000 ms), the ip should be retrieved later on so that I can ban it.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `uniq` and `awk`:

```
uniq -c log | awk '$1 >= 5 && /Packet was modified, sent by id:/'
```

Since the timestamps in the log file has a resolution of a second and since this is the time interval you're interested in, it is probably enough to count the unique lines in the file.

`uniq -c` will aggregate consecutive unique lines and add a count of how many of them there were. This will take the whole line into account, including the "id" and IP-address. `awk` then uses this count and outputs the ones with a count of five or more that also contains the string `Packet was modified, sent by id:`.

The case that this will *not* catch is if two or three log entries were done during one second, and another three or two were done during the following second (but then nothing else).

It will also not work if the log is unsorted (several different IPs producing intermingled log entries during the same second).

Comment: I doubt that would be enough to solve the problem, as the id and ip need to be the same as well. Also how do I execute that script ( I don't have any knowledge in shells) ?

Comment: @SeifHassine `uniq -c` will aggregate consecutive unique lines and add a count of how many of them there were.  This will take the whole line into account. `awk` uses this count.